# unable to locate the package mate-desktop-environment-core

Tags: raspbian-stretch, desktop

I am trying to install Mate desktop on my Raspberry Pi 3B with Rapsbian Stretch (RPD). I've followd the turorials i found on iternet to do this:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691

The problem is that when i use:

```
sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment-core
```

i get:

```
unable to locate the package mate-desktop-environment-core
```

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d is:

```
raspi.list
```

and its content is

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: First run `sudo apt update` before another try to install it. If that doesn't help then check the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list and all list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d and add these to your question.

Comment: I'va added to the question the content of the files requested.

Comment: Are you saying there are no files in directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d ?

Comment: And what about the upate / retry. I checked and your package should be available in the repo.

Comment: Sorry, i've thought it was a file not a directory.

Comment: I've did apt update and now it can find it. I don't know why it couldn't before. I've been trying to install it for the last couple of days and used apt update / upgrade many times.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: at some point there was an upgrade that changed one of the sources. It needed an 'update' *after* installation to get everything up to date. Several people reported this problem and I think you hit that one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'mate' package should be available in the Raspbian repository.
Try running `sudo apt update` before another install attempt.

A recent update changed the Raspbian apt source and it needs an extra `apt-get update` **after** `apt-get upgrade`